# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Src' - When I run a Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-import, discord.py

I am building a discord bot and I am having trouble importing the code with the functions that I want to test.

When I run my MemberRepositoryTest.py file it gives me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Src'
```

MemberRepositoryTest.py (/Tests/Src/Repositories/)

```
import pytest

from Src.Repositories import MemberRepository # <--- This line is failing.

# TODO: Implement tests
```

My folder structure is this on this link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPEZq.jpg

The tests structure is:

Tests/Src/Repositories/MemberRepositoryTest.py (Mirrors Src)

I am unsure why it is not finding my modules so I can import the classes and functions.

From my research online I think it may be a problem with my **init**.py files. However, being new to Python, I do not understand this fully. I read the Python documentation which explained it creates a package with the files inside as the modules. This means I have imported each file in the directory to the **init**.py file. However, I am still getting this issue.

Init file (on root directory):

```
import Src
```

Init file (/Src/):

```
import Cogs
import Entities
import Models
import Queries
import Repositories
import AppConfig
import DatabaseConnection
```

Init file (/Src/Repositories):

```
import GuildRepository
import MemberRepository
```

I run this from the root directory of the project (documents/rush_bot). The command I run to execute the test file is `pytest Tests/Src/Repositories/MemberRepository.py`

My Python Path Environment is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: I don't see those `__init__.py` files in the screenshot.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh apologies, I have updated the link to show the ```__init__.py``` files.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your PYTHONPATH env variable, the command you're using to run the test and which folder you're running it from?

Comment: @GabrielC I have added the information you requested. My PATH is finding python 2.7 but my bot has been running 3.7.4. Although I need to keep 2.7 because my twitch chatbot scripts require 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is failing to find your package since it is not in the PYTHONPATH.

You can either add your project folder to the PYTHONPATH or  `.`. If you add `.` then Python will always look for packages inside the current directory.

By the way, in this Init file (/Src/Repositories) you are importing modules without the full path.

```py
import Src.Repositories.GuildRepository
import Src.Repositories.MemberRepository
```